# Flatten list of lists containing a single item

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that consists of lists containing up to a single string, for example:

```cs
var fruits = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string>(),
    new List<string> { "Apple" },
    null,
    new List<string> { "Banana" },
};
```

I would like to extract the strings from the list above, not allowing the lists containing the strings to have more than one item. That is, I need to have the following result:

```cs
{ "Apple", "Banana" }
```

So far I have been trying the following:

```cs
var result = fruits
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => x.SingleOrDefault())
    .Where(x => x != null);
```

Is there a simpler solution to do this?

Comment: You can skip the first null-check: `fruits.Select(x => x?.SingleOrDefault().Where(x => x != null)`. You can also reduce the `Where(x => x != null)` to `OfType<string>()` if you feel so inclined

Comment: fruits.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x)

Comment: what should happen if there are 2 strings in the list?

Comment: @Mat, in case there is more than one string in the list, it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to select all unique items in lists to a single list, you can use `SelectMany()` and `Distinct()` for that:

```
fruits.Where(x=> x != null).SelectMany(x=> x).Distinct();
```

Comment: I don't think OP mentioned "unique"

Comment: hm... then what behavior is defined if the list contains more than one element?

Comment: "I have a list that consists of lists ***containing up to a single string***..." maybe you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Then we could use `Where(x => x?.Count == 1)` to achieve this result, couldn't we?

Comment: OP is deliberately using `SingleOrDefault` which throws when there is more than one element, which matches thie description of "not allowing the lists containing the strings to have more than one item"

Comment: @Serhii, if the lists have more than one string, an exception should be thrown. Whether the stings are unique or not is irrelevant. I just want to extract all strings while ensuring that each list has at most one string.

Comment: okey, then the answer was provided by canton7. Thanks for clarification